# keep the same jenkins agent pod for the main and underneath pipelines

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-pod

I am using jenkins and kubernetes,
each time I trigger a job a new inbound-agent pod is created to execute the job, so far so good.

However, pipelines having underneath pipelines is an issue:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'kubernetePod' }

  stages {
    
    stage('Building') {
        steps{
            build job: 'Build', parameters: []
        }
    }
    stage('Testing') {
        steps{
            build job: 'Test', parameters: []
         }
    }    
}
```

In this case, we have three pipelines

- 'main' pipeline having 'building' stage and 'testing 'stage
- 'build' pipeline
- 'test' pipeline

So a **pod 'A'** is created to execute the main pipeline,

then a **pod 'B'** is created to checkout and build the solution

finally a **pod 'C'** is created to execute solution tests **but it crashed** because the solution is contained in the **pod 'B'**.

**My question is how do I keep the pod 'A' for executing the underneath pipelines!**

thank you for your help.

best regards

Comment: The accepted answer shows how to retain a pod using `idleMinutes`. You may also individual pods for each build stage. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66474721/7991646).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Kubernetes slaves are designed to be stateless and are meant for single use.

The only workaround I think may help in some cases is to use `idleMinutes` to set how long the `Pod` should be in the `Running` state.
In your case if you use `idleMinutes` with appropriate values, you will be able to run `Build` and `Test` jobs using the same `Pod` (`podB` from your example).

---

I've created an example to illustrate you how it works.

This is the pipeline snippet:

```
pipeline {

  agent { kubernetes { 
            label 'test'
            idleMinutes "60"
        }}

  stages {
    
    stage('Building') {
        steps{
            build job: 'Build'
        }
    }
    stage('Testing') {
        steps{
            build job: 'Test'
    }    
}
}
}
```

This is the `Build` job:

```
node('test') {
    stage('Run shell') {
        sh 'touch /home/jenkins/test_file'
        sh 'echo 123abc > /home/jenkins/test_file'
    }
}
```

This is the `Test` job:
**NOTE:** This job reads the file created by the `Build` job.

```
node('test') {
    stage('Run shell') {
        sh 'cat /home/jenkins/test_file'
    }
}
```

As a result we can see that two Pods were created (`podA` and `podB` from your example) and they are still in the `Running` state:

```
# kubectl get pods
NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-99sfv-7fhw2   1/1     Running   0          4m45s
test-99sfv-vth3j   1/1     Running   0          4m25s
```

Additionally in the `test-99sfv-vth3j` `Pod` there is `test_file` created by the `Build` job:

```
# kubectl exec test-99sfv-vth3j -- cat /home/jenkins/test_file
123abc
```