# Jenkins Declarative: Kubernetes Plugin with multiple agents

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a Jenkins declarative pipeline to use two different agents during its execution. The agents are dynamically spawned by the Kubernetes plugin. For sake of argument and simplicity, let's assume I want to do this:

On Agent 1 (Cloud name: "ubuntu"):

- Run apt-get and some installs
- Run a shell script
- Additional steps

On Agent 2 (Cloud name: "fedora"):

- Run dnf and some installs
- Run a shell script
- Additional steps

The problem I have is that if if I use a global agent declaration:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      cloud 'ubuntu'
      label "ubuntu-agent"
      containerTemplate {
        name 'support'
        image 'blenderfox/support'
        ttyEnabled true
        command 'cat'
      }
    }
  }
...
}
```

Then that is used across all the stages if I don't declare an agent on each of the stages.

If I use `agent none`:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  ...
}
```

Then I have to declare an agent spec for each stage, for example:

```
    stage ("apt update") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'ubuntu'
          label "ubuntu-agent"
          containerTemplate {
            name 'support'
            image 'blenderfox/support'
            ttyEnabled true
            command 'cat'
          }
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        apt update
        """
      }
    }
```

While this would work for me in that I can declare per stage which agent I want, the problem this method causes, is that it spins up a new agent for *each* stage, meaning the state isn't carried between, for example, these two stages:

```
    stage ("apt-update") {
      agent {
        ....
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        apt update
        """
      }
    }
    stage ("apt-install") {
      agent {
        ....
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        apt install -y ....
        """
      }
    }
```

Can I reuse the same agent across stages? For example, something like this:

```
stage ("provision agent") {
  agent {
    ...
    label "ubuntu-agent"
    ...
  }
  steps {
    sh """
    echo "Provisioning agent"
    """
  }
}
stage ("apt-update") {
  agent {
    label "ubuntu-agent" //reuse agent from previous stage
  }
  steps {
    sh """
    apt update
    """
  }
}
stage ("apt-install") {
  agent {
    label "ubuntu-agent" //reuse agent from previous stage
  }
  steps {
    sh """
    apt install -y ....
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: You can keep an agent alive for reuse after completion (and make it wait x minutes for some other job to take it - but im not sure if you can specify - take exaclly this agent, it will more likely take first one that is available so not really 'stable' if you need prev one. Also I'd like to ask you question as well - did you figure out how to spawn multiple agents with multiple resource quotas at the same time ? atm. I have few jobs that need 9gb of ram and all other need 500mb top - kinda waste to run all jobs with high limits

Comment: @potatopotato probably the only way I can think of is by using different "cloud" definitions:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution. Very hacky but it works:

```
pipeline {

  agent none

  stages {
    stage ("Provision dev agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'dev-cloud'
          label "dev-agent-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
          slaveConnectTimeout 300
          idleMinutes 5
          yamlFile "jenkins-dev-agent.yaml"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        ## Do any agent init steps here
        """
      }

    }
    stage ("Do something on dev agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          label "dev-agent-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        ## Do something here
        """
      }
    }


    stage ("Provision production agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'prod-cloud'
          label "prod-agent-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
          slaveConnectTimeout 300
          idleMinutes 5
          yamlFile "jenkins-prod-agent.yaml"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        ## Do any agent init steps here
        """
      }
    }
    stage ("Do something on prod agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          label "prod-agent-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh """
        ## Do something here
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The agent yamls vary, but you can do something like this:

```
spec:
   containers:
   - name: docker
     image: docker:18.06.1
     command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
     imagePullPolicy: Always
     volumeMounts:
       - name: docker
         mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
   volumes:
   - hostPath:
      path: "/var/run/docker.sock"
     name: "docker"
```

And then use the agent like so:

```
stage ("docker build") {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label "dev-agent-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
  }
  steps {
    container('docker') {
      sh """
        ## docker build....
      """
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For others using this great solution: do not skip idleMinutes in the agent setting.
Without this, at least in my case, Jenkins tried to spawn a new agent with the same name but not on the cloud I intended.

Comment: Without the idleMinutes, the agent will terminate after its steps are done. The intention here is to leave the agent running for a bit so that the other steps can reuse that agent. And make sure the agent label is unique enough that another job doesn't accidentally pick it up

Comment: Thx @Blender Fox, that's what I wanted to point out. I tried adopting your solution, skipped that parameter and wondered why it didn't work. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution for this using [sequential stages](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/) - you define a stage with your agent, and then you can nest other stages inside it

```
pipeline {

  agent none

  stages {
    stage ("Provision dev agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'dev-cloud'
          slaveConnectTimeout 300
          yamlFile "jenkins-dev-agent.yaml"
        }
      }

      stages {
        stage ("Do something on dev agent") {
          steps {
            sh """
            ## Do something here
            """
          }
        }

        stage ("Do something else on dev agent") {
          steps {
            sh """
            ## Do something here
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage ("Provision prod agent") {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'prod-cloud'
          slaveConnectTimeout 300
          yamlFile "jenkins-prod-agent.yaml"
        }
      }

      stages {
        stage ("Do something on prod agent") {
          steps {
            sh """
            ## Do something here
            """
          }
        }

        stage ("Do something else on prod agent") {
          steps {
            sh """
            ## Do something here
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```